# Prove or disprove a claim involving Pythagorean primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues, sums-of-squares

As we know, every [Pythagorean prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_prime) $p$ is expressible as $p=x^2+y^2$ such that $x$ is an odd integer and $y$ is an even integer. Prove or disprove: $x$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Comment: This seems to be true up until $p=149$. I don't have a computer with me right now, though.

Comment: And 157.  hmmmm....

Answer (score 4):

It's true.

Divide $p$ by $x$ polynomially to get a perfect square remainder, $y^2$.  Then $p$ is a quadratic resudue mod $q$ where $q$ is any odd prime factor of $x$.  By quadratic reciprocity with $p$ a $4k+1$ prime, $q$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.  By multiplication $x$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.